# Set access permissions of ArcGIS Server Map Service with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I have a number of Map Services I create with an ArcPy script.
After publishing, I have to go to ArcGIS Server Manager to set the access permissions to "Everyone" by clicking on the heads symbol for every Map Service.

[image]

I would like to have an automatic solution to set the permissions with ArcPy after the Map Service is published.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Can you show the code you've used to publish? There are sharing settings on some of the arcpy functions. Otherwise you'll need to look at the [ArcGIS Python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/managing-your-gis-servers/) to set the values after the fact.

Comment: I tried it like this `arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(projectfolder + '\\' + agsLayerName + '.sd', con, in_public="PUBLIC", in_organization="SHARE_ORGANIZATION")`but it does not work

Comment: What I want, is this: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/sharing-a-service-with-your-arcgis-organization-using-manager.htm
Editing the sharing properties after publishing

Comment: Hmmm, my only thought it to set the **in_override** parameter to **OVERRIDE_DEFINITION**. If this doesnt work, I'll go as far as saying as you cant use the parameters you are to set sharing for an ARCGIS SERVER service. The help doc specifically talks about ArcGIS Online for these parameters. So, if this **in_override** doesn't work, you'll need to change sharing settings by making an HTTP REST call manually or using the ArcGIS Python API.